# Angular 2 or NodeJs / Express for large project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am not sure where Angular 2 stands with NodeJs/Express. Do Angular and Node work together or can you only use one of them for a web project?

Comment: Angular & Node works really good with each other. They are different thing, Angular -> Frontend(client), NodeJS -> Backend(server)

Comment: I think you are confused. Angular is a Front end framework. Node/Express are back end frameworks. They work wonderfully together. They don't conflict at all.

Comment: NodeJs is Javascript too which works on the server side, but so can Angular 2 ... is it using Nodejs to do this?

Comment: @Satch3000 no, it can't.

Comment: Everyone already answered that yes, they are indeed different from each other. Advantages of using Angular with Node is firstly that you will be using same language for frontend and backend so that makes it a little easier. Secondly, Angular js compliments Node Js (Express Js again is a framework that is used generally for middleware functionality over node.js). In short go ahead with Express with Angular - if it suits your job. Please read advantages of node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular allows you to build a complete web application without the need for Node.js

Without Node.js and express you will need to sort out a web server however. You could use Apache, Nginx or another if you have a preference.

However, if you are looking to create a backend or API that your frontend communicates with then you could introduce Node.js and develop an API. You could use other frameworks or tools for that however.

You could also use some Node modules in conjunction with a build tool (e.g. Grunt) to optimize your frontend assets like CSS, JS, Images etc. This would allow you more control over the condition of static assets served to the client after a build is completed.

In summary you can build a complete web application with Angular without the need for Node.js but Node will allow you to have more control over your project assets and if you want will allow you to create a separate application that supports your front-end.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, Angular And node are differents
Angular is a very powerful front-end framework that let you use a MVC structure at client side, whereas Node.js is a impletation of Javascript at server side, that let you make "active" servers (With Node, you can do asynchronous tasks, it is not only generate webpage with scripting. For exemple, it is great to use for websocket, a thing that you can't do in PHP).

However, it is a good solution for a web application, because both uses Javascript, and use natively Json for requests.

But currently, I'm working in a PHP project with angular2 at client side. It stays better than jQuery or other frameworks because of MVC structure, but when you use it with PHP, you have to make some arrangements (for example, when you send a POST request with angular, data are encoded with JSON, a thing that PHP does not understand: So I used in my client side a function that convert a JSON object to a simple urlEncoded string...)

I hope I answered your question,

Vincent

Comment: PHP and [json](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Comment: Yep, but for me it is harder to parse a POST request (with UrlEncoded, it is simple, you just use $_POST and filter_input, but with a JSON one, you have to use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, then parse it with json_decode, then validate it...)

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 is for front-end code, Node is 'typically' for the back-end.

Node however can be used to serve up the front end. (Most people either don't know this or forget it). Some people also use Node as a task runner to minify client side code, pre-process client side code, etc

For example using node you can convert LESS or SASS or STYLUS files into CSS files on the fly, and the CSS files are then served to your browser.

Live reload performs live updates to CSS or code changes without the need to do a browser refresh.

Task runners can auto inject Bower script dependencies. Popular Node task runners that simplify this process of serving up client side code are Grunt and Gulp.

Obviously, in a production environment you won't use a task runner. Task runners are meant for development purposes or for build purposes.

We are using Node's Gulp to serve up in development environment. We use Gulp also for the build. But in production we serve up the static build generated files over NGINX.

The downside of all this is the amount of effort to get a good pipeline in place.